# Do we have mysqli_affected_rows equivalent for Amazon Redshift Copy command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Just wanted to know if it is possible to get **number of records loaded/failed** using `Amazon Redshift` [Copy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html) Command fired through PHP script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for the `pg_last_copy_count` query.

From the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/PG_LAST_COPY_COUNT.html):

> Returns the number of rows that were loaded by the last COPY command
>   executed in the current session. PG_LAST_COPY_COUNT is updated with
>   the last COPY ID, which is the query ID of the last COPY that began
>   the load process, even if the load failed. The query ID and COPY ID
>   are updated when the COPY command begins the load process.

Comment: That's what I wanted, Thank you!